# commenting on facebook externally

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

How can i comment on a facebook post externally? i.e. through my web page?

I can like a post this way but can't seem to find a way to comment on it. I have added a comment box and given it the url to the facebook post but it does not show up there, only on my page or publishes it to the user's wall who is commenting but not on the actual post.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik it is not possible. The Comments Plugin cannot be connected to a specific post on facebook. There seem to be no way with the API either:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/

You can "like", "delete" and "read" a comment throught the API, but not create comments. I guess this is for security and spam reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There's no prebuilt social plugin for this but the regular API supports adding comments to most types of objects and it's quite straightforward.

Request the `publish_stream` permission from your users, and for most types of objects (examples being [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) and [Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) objects) you can make a POST to `/<object ID>/comments?message=message goes here&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

This obviously doesn't work for URLs, as there's no ability to post comments on URLs except via the comments plugin